# How to hide keyboard for samsung galaxy note programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using data and time picker for two edit text, I want to hide keyboard for two edit text.I am doing like this

```
mDatePickerEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.createwedding_datepicker_edt);
mTimePickerEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.createwedding_timepicker_edt);
mDatePickerEdt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
mTimePickerEdt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

it is working for smart phones.I getting problem in samsung galaxy note.If any one have idea.Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use following code to hide keyboard.

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I use these also.problem getting in samsung galaxy note.

Comment: @sai: check above edited code.. it may work.
I have used that code with tablet also its working.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or try input InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS instead of 0

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

you can use below code to suppress the keyboard until the user touched the edittext view.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```