# Hide soft-keyboard or forcibly change the focus to hide the keyboard

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom listview in a relative layout and for the life of me, I can not figure out why my soft-keyboard continues to display. From what I've researched a "default" item has the focus and if applicable the soft-keyboard will show. There is an initial login layout prior, to the next activity starting. The soft-keyboard should display when the user initially enters their credentials and attempts to login. However, the next activity is my summary.xml and the soft-keyboad continues to display after the user has logged in. I've tried a few different methods on this site and from search results, but I think the problem *may be isolated to my layouts.* **How can I hide the soft-keyboard immediately after a login is attempted?**

[image]
I've included my xml layouts below.

login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

            <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button" style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

summary.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.myapp.Summary">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Welcome" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Welcome"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

custom_listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldValue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why the above method did not work, so for giggles I googled to see if there was a "Samsung" specific solution and tada! (Hope this does not break it on other brands.)

[How to hide keyboard for samsung galaxy note programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696848/how-to-hide-keyboard-for-samsung-galaxy-note-programmatically-in-android)